# Stream specifier in filtergraph description matches no streams

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i WachAuf.mp4 -i WachAufM.mp4 -i WachAufR.mp4
```

yields

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'WachAuf.mp4':
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 88 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 248 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'WachAufM.mp4':
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 33 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'WachAufR.mp4':
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 251 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

yet

```
ffmpeg -i WachAuf.mp4 -i WachAufM.mp4 -i WachAufR.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [2:v] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" WachAuf.mkv
```

yields

```
Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [2:v] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: Add -report and run. Share report.

Comment: I found that `ffmpeg -i WachAuf.mp4 -i WachAufM.mp4 -i WachAufR.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" WachAuf.mkv` worked. Then I had to add audio later. It seems that ffmpeg cannot deal with only one audio present.

Comment: Ah yes, for each segment, all stream types which are being output, should be present.